# Adding paths to RequireJS configuration on runtime

Tags: requirejs, azure-mobile-services

Ok, I already know that you should configure paths with `RequireJS` like this

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    name: 'value'
  }
});
```

And call it like this.

```
require(['name'], function() {
    /* loaded */
});
```

But the thing is, I'm working in environment in which I don't have access to the existing call to `require.config(...)`. For those who care, the environment is Azure Mobile Services scheduled job. Microsoft has already included RequireJS in the environment and configured the paths. My question is two-fold.

**1. How do I add paths to the existing require.config()?**
I know calling `require.config()` again will destroy the existing configuration. Which is what I do not want to do.

**2. How do I get to know which paths have already been configured?**
I really wouldn't like to overwrite any existing path name or overwrite any existing library by accident.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Running require.config() again does not override your original config file. It actually extends it and adds your new paths to it. Right now I am using it this way, where `configfile` is also a `require.config({})`

```
<script data-main="configfile" src="require.js"></script>
<script>
    require.config({
        paths: {
            prefix-name: 'path/to/file'
        }
    });
</script>
```

One way to avoid name collisions with  Azure Mobile paths would be to simply prefix all your custom paths.

**Disclaimer:** I have never used Azure Mobile, just RequireJs. You may have to implement it a little differently but it is possible.

Comment: Thanks. Azure Mobile Services is in fact a node.js environment. So, normal require.js methods should apply.

Comment: How do you run the newly added path?